# How to scale image view in relation to widget height but respect a maximum height?

Tags: android, resize, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I'm currently developing an Android widget that contains an image view.
The widget is supposed to be resizable.

The image should fill the whole width of the widget (that's the easy part) and should fill 30% of the widget's height while respecting a maximum height of 80dip (that's what I can't figure out).

In the following layout, the image scales properly to the width, but not to the height:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/promoShelf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/shelf"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to use a LinearLayout with weights to get this done, which can be seen in the following snippet. However, it looks like `android:maxHeight` is not respected, when weights are used.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weight_sum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:maxHeight="80dip"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, this is the (unwanted) outcome:

[image]

Why is `maxHeight` not working or does anybody have an idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a good solution that uses only standart components. But it can be easily done using custom `ImageView` widget.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    private float weight = 0.3f;
    private int maxHeight;

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (attrs != null) {
            final int[] ids = {android.R.attr.maxHeight};
            final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ids);

            if (array != null) {
                maxHeight = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
                array.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (maxHeight > 0) {
            final int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            final int result = Math.min(Math.round(height * weight), maxHeight);

            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(result, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

And then in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0f0">

    <com.example.MyImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:maxHeight="80dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi vmironov. Thanks for the answer. As far as I know, custom widgets or subclasses are not supported in Android app widgets, unfortunately... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try this:

Wrap the `ImageView` in a container. Let the container be 30% of the `LinearLayout`'s height. The `ImageView` is attached to the `bottom` of the container and the `ImageView` will have a max-height of `80dp`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:maxHeight="80dip"
                android:src="@drawable/my_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
               />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the maxHeight is still not respected in your approach. I don't quite understand why, though...

Comment: Ok, after playing around a bit, I found out that it actually works your way. The only thing I had to change was to set `android:layout_height` of the ImageView to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. Additionally, there is one more thing that would have to be changed in your code if it is to be used for an app widget: As "View" is not a supported widget type for RemoteViews, `View` should be changed to `ImageView`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just found out what the reason for the necessity of `wrap_content` is: `maxHeight` still has no effect. Using `wrap_content`, the ImageView doesn't scale higher than the image's original height, but still shrinks if the parent's height descreases. So, to get the above code working as expected, one has to make sure that the used image has a height of 160px (i.e. maxHeight). I would still like to know, why maxHeight doesn't seem to work when weights are used...

Comment: The problem is that maxHeight & fill_parent (maxHeight & layout_weight) are contradictory. You instruct it to fill its parent, but if it reaches maxHeight, then don't :-). I guess the code in the child's onMeasure receives a spec of MeasureSpec.EXACTLY when layout_width and fill_parent is used, telling it to ignore any maxHeight and such.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i know its not a really good solution but this is the only one i have in my mind as of now :P

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weight_sum="1">
 <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.7"
android:background="#000000"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:maxHeight="80dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#800000"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />

  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Droidee. Thanks, but unfortunately this has the same result as the code in my questions, i.e. the maxHeight ist not respected.